# Standard way to disconnect from database in cherrypy?

Tags: cherrypy, zodb

I'm using zodb with cherrypy.  I'm passing data into a jinja2 template.  I would like to close my zodb connection before I return the template render.

I can't because the template needs the connection when it's rendering because the data is zodb data.

This errors out...

```
zconn.close() #zconn.close closes the conn,db, and storage
return template.render(args....)
```

How do I close down the zodb conn after I'm already finished returning?  Is there some "before request" and "after request" function I can define to always have a db connection?  The cherrypy documentation doesn't have much explicit stuff on database connections save for "do it explicitly at the beginning of the exposed function - and close it before you return".

Or is it standard practice to say...

```
page = template.render(args...)
zconn.close()
return page
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is standard practice to only close the connection when the request is complete, yes.

Postpone the close to the latest possible moment. Use could use a context manager to handle the closing for you:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def zodbconn(db):
    conn = db.open()
    yield conn.root()
    conn.close()
```

then use:

```
with zodbconn(db) as zconn:
    return template.render(args....)
```

and the connection will be closed automatically *after* the `return` statement has been processed.

Comment: @MKaras: sure, but then you need to open the connection first, then use `with closing(zconn):` as the context manager, in each method.